# A smart python program that renames file names

Tags: python, python-2.7, rename

So, I was making a python program that renames A.txt to B.txt, but I wanted the program to skip and move on if there is file "B.txt" already in the folder. Meanwhile, if there is neither A or B in the folder, then there is something wrong so I want the program to show me error and stop.

So I wanted "if A exists then rename it, if neither A nor B exists then show me error and stop the program, if only B exists then move on to next line"

What I did is this.

```
import os
os.rename('A.txt','Btxt')
```

But if there is no A.txt, the program stops and shows me error message. How can I code what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only rename A.txt if it exists and B.txt does not.

In case A.txt does not exists it checks that B.txt does.

```
import os

if os.path.isfile("A.txt"):
    if not os.path.isfile("B.txt"):
        os.rename('A.txt','B.txt')
else:
    assert os.path.isfile("B.txt") , "Neither A.txt or B.txt exists"
```